# Migrating constants to a property file but filter can't access the props file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, filter, thymeleaf, application.properties

I am updating a Spring Boot web application that uses Thymeleaf.  My goal is to externalize values of the variables in a Constants class that a Spring Boot Filter class uses.  I need to move the String constants into the external application.properties file and alter the constants class so that the values in the constants class are now coming from the application.properties file.

NOTE:  I am not allowed to copy code samples publicly so I am providing a generic example code for what I did in the actual project.

I have created new keys & values based off of the constants in the Constants class and put these keys & values into the already implemented application.properties file in the project.  Here is an example of a key and value in the application.properties file:

```
dept1.segment.text=Segment source is under review.
```

I then made the following changes to the Constants.java class:

```
//Added these annotations
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Constants {
   //added this @Value
   @Value("${dept1.segment.text}")
   public static String SEGMENT_TEXT;
}
```

I implemented a test by adding a call to the Constants class in my controller class and passed the value of Constants.SEGMENT_TEXT into my main index page to see if the value came through.

```
model.addAttribute("segmentedText", Constants.SEGMENT_TEXT);
```

Then added a span on my home page to display the value:

```
<span th:text="${segmentedText}">props populated text</span>
```

This didn't work - My project builds with no errors and deploys but segmentedText is blank in the home page.

In the end, I need my Filter class to have values from the application.properties file outside of my project.  I can access properties from my properties file in my controllers in the project so I know there isn't an issue with the application.properties file in my project.  The Filter class uses the Constants class in multiple places in the "doFilter" method of the class so it seemed easier to just alter the Constants class but I also tried to simply add @Value's (like I do in the Controller class) in the Filter class and that didn't seem to work either.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:  I figured out one thing that almost solves this...but not quite.  For my test...I instantiated my Constants class in my controller for my home page so that I could then add an attribute to the model so my page could display the contents of the SEGMENT_TEXT...well I shouldn't have instantiated the Constants class...instead I now "@Autowired" it and now my value for SEGMENT_TEXT is showing up in the home page BUT I still can't get these prop values into my filter class... when I try to add "@Component" to my Filter class I get an error:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myFilter' defined in VFS resource ["/C:/jboss-eap-7.3/bin/content/my-portal.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/me/portal/myFilter.class"]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager must be specified`

and then if I try to "@Autowired" my Constants class in there it doesn't work.  So I still can't get application.properties properties into my Filter class.

Answer (score 1):

That's because Spring doesn't support `@Value` **on static fields.**

It works if you create a method called `setSegmentText` and annotate it with `@Value` annotation. This setter handles the our `SEGMENT_TEXT` value.

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Constants {

    public static String SEGMENT_TEXT;

    @Value("${dept1.segment.text}")
    public void setSegmentText(String value) {
        Constants.SEGMENT_TEXT = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ismail Y., I tried what you said and it didn't make a difference.   However, after I added the setter that you described, I realized what I mentioned up in my Question in the UPDATE portion.  I then removed the setter you suggested and without it I am still seeing the property in my Home page.

Comment: Oh by the way! @Ismail Y., Even though everything you stated was exactly what I needed, I did remove the static portion and that part helped.  Thank you.